# Groups of radio-buttons contains groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to make a list of radio buttons that contain a group of check boxes and these in turn contain another group checkboxes:

My code works fine when I use in one radio button. If I select another one JS is returned something strange, and I do not know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="level-1">submenu1.1
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.1.1
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.1.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.1.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.1.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.1.2
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.2.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.2.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.2.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.1.3
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.3.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.3.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.3.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.1.4
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.4.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.4.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.1.4.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <br>

    <li class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="level-1" value="submenu">submenu1.2
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.2.1
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.1.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.1.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.1.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.2.2
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.2.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.2.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.2.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.2.3
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.3.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.3.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.3.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.2.4
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.4.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.4.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3">submenu1.2.4.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <br>

    <li class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="level-1">submenu1.3
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.3.1
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.1.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.1.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.1.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.3.2
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.2.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.2.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.2.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.3.3
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.3.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.3.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.3.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">submenu1.3.4
          <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.4.1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.4.2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-3" value="submenu">submenu1.3.4.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li:not(.radio)").hide();
  $("input[name='level-1']").change(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $("li:not(.radio)").hide();
    var $val = $(this).next("ul").children("li");
    $val.slideToggle("fast");
    $val.next("ul").children("li").hide();

    $("input[type=checkbox][name='level-2']").click(function (event) {
      $(this).next("ul").children("li").slideToggle("fast");
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if (!checked) {
        $(this).parent().find("input[type=checkbox][name='level-3']").prop("checked", false);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/benatespina/Et95z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are triggering `level-2` change event inside `level-1` change event.

Write them separately.

Write:

```
  $("li:not(.radio)").hide();
  $("input[name='level-1']").change(function () {
      console.log(this);
      $("li:not(.radio)").hide();
      var $val = $(this).next("ul").children("li");
      $val.slideToggle("fast");
      $val.next("ul").children("li").hide();
      $("input[type=checkbox][name='level-2']:checked").removeAttr("checked");
  });
  $("input[type=checkbox][name='level-2']").change(function (event) {
      $(this).next("ul").find("li").slideToggle("fast");
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if (!checked) {
          $(this).parent().find("input[type=checkbox][name='level-3']").prop("checked", false);
      }
  });
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Et95z/2/)

Comment: Ouch, it was a stupid error! Thanks a lot!! One more thing: if I want to clean the checkbox of `level-1` when I change the radio-button?

Comment: @benatespina welcome :) write `$("input[type=checkbox][name='level-2']:checked").removeAttr("checked");` [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Et95z/2/)